# How to restart a posix thread from another thread (monitor thread in my case)

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, deadlock

I am trying to handle a deadlock situation and need to restart a deadlocked thread from the monitor thread by resource pre-emption and rollback strategy for posix threads..Im clueless about how to restart a thread from another thread ,Kindly help!

Comment: why is it deadlocked? That's the question to answer before even considering _restarting deadlocked code_. Can you post some relevant code snippets?

Comment: Your app is dead.  You cannot ressurect it.  Fix the design to make the deadlock go away.

Comment: I second this - the right way to deal with deadlocks is to prevent them rather than try to recover from them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "restarting" is a common and well-defined operation provided by typical thread implementations. I certainly didn't find any in pthreads, which I assume you're using.

What would a "restart" involve, exactly? How is it different from (somehow) destroying/stopping the thread, and starting a new one with the same code and data?

Comment: Exactly! Forcibly stopping a thread is usually a bad idea in general.

Comment: Pausing and/or resuming a thread at users convinience may not be such a bad idea in general.

Comment: unwind is right, though. If you have deadlock, then you have a thread waiting for a condition that will never be true (acquire some mutex that will never be unlocked, waiting on a semaphore that will never be posted). You can't resolve this just by "restarting" that stuck thread, because what would the thread do next? It can't continue executing code that assumes it has the mutex when it doesn't. Deadlock recovery is more complex than that.

Comment: If it's deadlocked, it's dead. Deader than dead. Deader than 'Dead' Jock McDead.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Oups, comment was on Code Painters comment. I completely agree to unwinds statement.

Comment: @martin: true by definition, I suppose, but there are techniques to recover from certain classes of things that *would* be deadlocks if you let them be. For example by allowing the thing to happen and then figuring out what to kill to unblock everything else. Of course it's normally only worth doing that as a last-ditch defense against dodgy code on a system that's supposed to be resilient. You'd always prefer not to write code that makes that thing happen in the first place.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Martin is right and you are rigth too (per definition). Any procedure which recovers from a lock of any kind will cause the code to not deadlock. Thus: deadlock is as dead as dead can be. So the hint for Jessica: Why is it stuck?

Comment: @Arno: well, I assumed that it's more about killing the thread than pausing it. Deadlocked thread may as well hold some resources that would never be reclaimed if it's forcibly destroyed, etc. Looking at the comments, I see we all agree that it's like trying to fix the symptoms instead of of solving the root cause of the problem :)

Comment: Question wanted the threads to deadlock and we should write a program to detect and rollback that thread - assignment is done now :)